# Serializing and deserializing a list of objects in a Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

Given some list of objects:

```
List<Car> carlist = new List<Car>();
```

How can I serialize this list as an XML or binary file and deserialize it back?

I have this so far but it doesn't work.

```
//IsolatedStorageFile isFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
//IsolatedStorageFileStream ifs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myxml.xml", FileMode.Create,isFile);
//DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer();
//XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ifs);
//ser.WriteObject(writer, carlist);
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, you need to state how it is not working for you. What are you expecting? What is actually happening? Etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using these methods to Save and Load from a XML file in/to the IsolatedStorage :

```
public static class IsolatedStorageOperations
{
    public static async Task Save<T>(this T obj, string file)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = null;

                try
                {
                    stream = storage.CreateFile(file);
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        stream.Close();
                        stream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    public static async Task<T> Load<T>(string file)
    {

        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        if (storage.FileExists(file))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = null;
            try
            {
                stream = storage.OpenFile(file, FileMode.Open);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));

                obj = (T) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                    stream.Dispose();
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
        await obj.Save(file);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

You can customize the error handling in the catch().

Also, you can adjust the Load method to your needs, in my case I am trying to load from a file and if doesn't exist, it creates a default one and puts the default serialized object of the type provided according to the constructor.

**UPDATE :**

Let's say you have that list of cars :

`List< Car > carlist= new List< Car >();`

To save, you can just call them as  `await carlist.Save("myXML.xml");` , as it is an asynchronous `Task`(`async`).

To load, `var MyCars = await IsolatedStorageOperations.Load< List< Car> >("myXML.xml").` (I think, I haven't used it like this, as a List so far...

Answer (score 0):

DataContactJsonSerializer performs better than XmlSerializer. It creates smaller files and handles well lists inside properties.

Comment: Can you please provide some example or references?

Comment: @ waghekapil: based on my own experience. You can try to serialize object with having inside property of List, and it will be skipped by XmlSerializer. Also about size - in general, XML having a larger structure than JSON.

Comment: thanks! I've done it through the DataContactJsonSerializer :)