# Error when call the IsolatedStorage.Load method (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I was looking for writing objects in the Storage in Windows Phone 8 at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514710/serializing-and-deserializing-a-list-of-objects-in-a-windows-phone-8-app?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Everything worked well but when I call The Load method with: `IsolatedStorageOperations.Load<Friend>("myXML.xml")`

I always get the Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task 
                          <'friendsbook.Lib.Friend'>' to 'friendsbook.Lib.Friend'
```

It also doesn't work with:

```
IsolatedStorageOperations.Load("myXML.xml")
```

But call the Save method is no problem!!!

Can anybody help me on this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `IsolatedStorageOperations.Load<Friend>`method is asynchronous, use the `await` keyword when calling it:

```
var friend = await IsolatedStorageOperations.Load<Friend>("myXML.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But you can only use await within an async method

Comment: Alternatively, you can call the method synchronously: `var friend = IsolatedStorageOperations.Load<Friend>("myXML.xml").Result;`